# gitignore fails to ignore files/folders with whitespaces

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my .gitignore file:

```
Textfusion\ Pro/bin/Debug/
Textfusion\ Pro/bin/Release/
.gitignore
.vs/
```

But If I execute `git status` then the folder is still appearing.

[image: t]

I also tried it like this:

- Textfusion Pro/bin/Release/
- Textfusion*Pro/bin/Release/
- "Textfusion Pro"/bin/Release/
- "Textfusion Pro/bin/Release/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files are already in the repository. You have to `git rm` them (note that you should specify the `--cached` option to `git rm` if you don't want them to be deleted). After that, they should be ignored if you write it like `Textfusion Pro/bin/Release/` in the `.gitignore` file.

Note that even after you do that and commit, they will still be in the repository history, taking up space. There are questions on Stackoverflow that explain how to rewrite the git history.

Comment: I get `Unknown option: -rm`

Comment: @Black it looks like you have accidentally inserted a `-` character

Comment: This will delete the files... I don't want to delete them

Comment: It won't delete the files if you do `git rm --cached`